# Wrong reaction to proper Contact Form shortcode by do_shortcode()

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

I've written a sample of code:

```
$aboutProductShortcode =  get_option('prod_cf_short');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($aboutProductShortcode);
var_dump('[contact-form-7 id="96" title="title"]');
echo '</pre>';
echo do_shortcode($aboutProductShortcode);
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="96" title="title"]');
```

Which gives me that results:

```
string(70) "[contact-form-7 id="96" title="title"]"
string(50) "[contact-form-7 id="96" title="title"]"
[contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"]
<here is properly displayed contact form>
```

What's the matter? I don't have a clue, but I need to have that shortcode readen from the option - hard coding is not the point.

Answer (score 0):

Done!

While writing option to the database by settings page, the register_settings() function had attribute "esc_attr" which changed the " to &qout - which was translated back to " on display.